# Stop audio loop Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, audio

I have the following code:

```
   var player = document.createElement('audio');
player.src = 'https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7079101/coin.mp3';
player.preload = 'auto';

   var url= 'http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/update.html';

window.setInterval(function(){
  if($("*:contains(Update')").length > 0){
    console.log('New Update, playing sound...');
    player.play();
  }
}, 5000);
```

> Credits: Laurens Swart

The code works great, however, the audio loops forever. Is there any way to make the audio play just once?

Comment: Use `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval`

Comment: I may have some problem with the authorities of my hosting country by helping you, so this will stay as a comment, but if the goal is to check when one element with `Update` in it has been added to the doc, and play the sound at this moment, then you've to know that `setInterval` does return an id, which be used with [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) method, when your check passes. If you're waiting for multiple such events, then change `> 0` to `> current` and increment `current` at every new positive event.

Comment: @Kim Jong-un  once you nail this ... if you do ... post an answer to help the next person ... welcome to SO

Answer (score 0):

You are using `window.setInterval` This will repeat the call to `player.play()` forever until you call `clearInterval()`.

If you want the player to play only once I suggest you use `window.setTimeout` instead.

```
var player = document.createElement('audio');
player.src = 'https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7079101/coin.mp3';
player.preload = 'auto';

   var url= 'http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/update.html';

window.setTimeout(function(){
  if($("*:contains(Update')").length > 0){
    console.log('New Update, playing sound...');
    player.play();
  }
}, 5000);
```

Comment: That was a good solution, however, when a new Update appears on the site, the script can´t frigger the audio anymore because it has been already played. I think that what I need is a listener. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove you setinterval to play your audio once 
And add loop attribute of audio to false

try this :

```
var player = document.createElement('audio');
player.src = 'https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7079101/coin.mp3';
player.preload = 'auto';
player.loop = false;
var url = 'http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/update.html';

// window.setInterval(function () {
        if ($("*:contains(Update')").length > 0) {
            console.log('New Update, playing sound...');
            player.play();
        }
// }, 5000);
```

Comment: If I comment those lines the script do not execute.